# How to get the value of the jquery range slider in angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, rangeslider

I am able to drag the slider but i don't how to get the values of the slider ..

```
ngOnInit() {             
    jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find("#slider").slider({
        range:true,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        step:1,
        value: [80, 100],

        slide: function (event, ui) {


        }
    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as described below:

```
ngOnInit() {             
  jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find("#slider").slider({
    (...)
    slide: ( event, ui ) => {
      this.slideValue = ui.value;
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the use of an arrow function to be able to set the value in the component property `slideValue`.

**Edit**

You can wrap the slider into an ngModel-compliant component. Here is a sample implementation:

```
const SLIDER_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, {useExisting: forwardRef(() => SliderComponent), multi: true});

@Component({
  selector: 'slider',
  template: `
    <div class="slider"></div>
  `,
  providers: [ SLIDER_VALUE_ACCESSOR ]
})
export class SliderComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef) {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sliderElt = $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find('.slider');
    this.sliderElt.slider({
      range:true,
      orientation: "horizontal",
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      step:1,
      range: false,
      value: this.value,
      slide: (event, ui) => {
        this.onChange(ui.value);
      }
    });
    this.initialized = true;
  }

  writeValue(value:any):void {
    if (value!=null) {
      if (this.initialized) {
        this.sliderElt.slider('value', value);
      } else {
        this.value = value;
      }
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```

And use it this way:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app'
  template: `
    <div>
      <slider [(ngModel)]="sliderValue"></slider>
      sliderValue: {{sliderValue}}<br/>
      <div (click)="updateValue()">update value</div>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [ SliderComponent ]
})
export class App {
  sliderValue = 0;

  updateValue() {
    this.sliderValue = 40;
  }
}
```

See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/GJZUakH6O2wclHxpwOP2?p=preview

You could have a look at this article for more details in section "NgModel-compatible component":

- http://restlet.com/blog/2016/02/17/implementing-angular2-forms-beyond-basics-part-2/

Comment: i want to assign this.slideValue to a global variable whenever the variable changes its value?

Comment: How to bind this.slideValue to the [(ngModel)]??

Comment: You want to wrap the slider into an `ngModel`-compliant component?

Comment: whever iam using this one,the table contents are flickering and changing

Answer (score 0):

why not just simply do

```
  updateValue() {
    this.sliderValue = 40;
    this.sliderElt.slider('value', this.sliderValue)
  }
```

Put that function inside slider component, or is it important to call it from the outside ?